# Android restart service correctly after app is closed

Tags: java, android, service, background-service, long-running-processes

I am currently developing an email application which relies on a background `service` in order to be able to automatically fetch new emails. This works perfectly when the application is open (or in the running list of apps) but as soon as I close the app / remove it from the recent apps list, the `service` is also stopped. This can be confirmed by going into the 'Developer Settings' on the device and seeing that there are no processes or services running for my application.

I have read countless threads on StackOverflow but none of them seem to be doing the trick. Sometimes `onTaskRemoved`() is called and the service is restarted but then other times it isn't called at all or it is called, the logs show that the OS has scheduled a restart of the `service` but then the `service` gets `forced closed` by the OS whereas I always need to have this service running to retrieve new emails.

My current code can be seen below:

**My Service:**

```
 @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");

        ...

        Log.d(TAG, "SERVICE IS RUNNING");

        if (host != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "STARTING PUSH SERVICE");

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BR: " + ((BugReporting) getApplication()));
                    sharedRunnable = ((BugReporting) getApplication()).getSharedRunnable();

                    MailPush mailPush = new MailPush(getApplicationContext(), sharedRunnable);
                    Log.d(TAG, "sharedRunnable 1: " + sharedRunnable);
                    mailPush.checkInboxEmail(host, email, password);
                    //mailPush.checkSentEmail(host, email, password);
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);//0.5 seconds

        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()");

        PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(),
                1001,
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
```

**Reboot Receiver:**

```
 public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

...

        <receiver
                android:name="uk.co.tundracorestudios.securemail.notification.AutoStart"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":remote">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <service
                android:name="uk.co.tundracorestudios.securemail.notification.MyService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/mail_service"
                android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

I did attempt to run `MyService` as a different `process` but this then restricted me from getting the `sharedRunnable` that I have saved in the application class which can otherwise be access through:

```
 updateListRunnable = ((BugReporting) getApplication()).getSharedRunnable();
```

Therefore, I am asking, how can I ensure that my `service` continuously runs / works even when the application is closed or when the device is `rebooted` whilst still having access to the components located in `getApplication()`?

As when I attempted to run `MyService` as a separate `process`, the above `updateListRunnable` would always return null whereas when the application and `service` were running in the same `process`, it would return the correct `runnable`.

Comment: Do you have your solution?

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue a while back and used this in the onDestroy() method of my service:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),1,restartService,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,5000,pendingIntent);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

When the service is being destoyed I set an alarm of 5 second, which will start my service aagain. This way your service will stop when user remove it from recent but it will start again.

Comment: Correct. `onTaskRemoved` is not part of a services lifecycle methods: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle

`onTaskRemoved` description is here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Thank you nullvoid! I have literally tried every solution provided on the internet, this has solved my problem where the force closed app is not getting notifications. Almost a 1 month struggle! Thank you for sharing your solution!

Comment: Uhm..Services have `onDestroy()` method?

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting the service using AlarmManager from onDestroy didn't work but starting the service from onTaskRemoved worked. When you kill the app while a service is running the onTaskRemoved function is triggered.

```
@Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTaskRemoved: removed");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000);
((AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterReceiverService.class), 0));
            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        }
```

So basically once you kill the app the service will be started after 10 seconds.
Note: In case you want to use

```
AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
```

the minimum time after which you'll be able to restart the service will be 15 minutes.

Remember you also need to start the service on reboot using BroadcastReceiver.